# image cropper package source path error in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-image, flutter-assetimage

i have to crop image when click double tap on image container that time image crop function call.

```
onDoubleTap: () {
            _cropImage(context);
          },
```

this image i have to direct to crop no new screen or not to use pick image direct this image i have to crop.

```
child: Image.asset(
                  'images/rose1.png',
                  width: width,
                  height: height,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
```

when this function call that time i have to show error of the sorce path not work.

```
  Future<void> _cropImage(BuildContext context) async {
    File? _croppedImage;

    final croppedImage = await ImageCropper().cropImage(
      sourcePath: 'images/rose1.png', // Replace with your image path
      aspectRatioPresets: [
        CropAspectRatioPreset.square,
        CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio3x2,
        CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
        CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio4x3,
        CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio16x9
      ],
      uiSettings: [AndroidUiSettings(
        toolbarTitle: 'Crop Image',
        toolbarColor: Colors.deepOrange,
        toolbarWidgetColor: Colors.white,
        initAspectRatio: CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
        lockAspectRatio: false,
      ),
    ],
    );

    if (croppedImage != null) {
      File? file = File(croppedImage.path);
      setState(() {
        _croppedImage = file;
      });
    }
  }
```

this error is show how to fix it.

> [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:image_cropper_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_image_cropper.dart': Failed assertion: line 72 pos 12: 'await File(sourcePath).exists()': is not true.
> E/flutter ( 9666): #0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:51:61)
> E/flutter ( 9666): #1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:40:5)
> E/flutter ( 9666): #2      MethodChannelImageCropper.cropImage (package:image_cropper_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_image_cropper.dart:72:12)
> E/flutter ( 9666): 
> E/flutter ( 9666): #3      _MovableImageBoxState._cropImage (package:invitation_card_app/widgets/MovableImageBox.dart:434:26)
> E/flutter ( 9666):

Answer (score 0):

Whenever there is an issue related to the method channel while installing a new package, you should consider to clean your pub cache from your system as the package might be having some conflicts with the other cached packages in your system.
So just run

##### Step 1

```
flutter pub cache clean
```

##### Step 2

```
flutter pub get
```

**And voila!** You won't have issues running your package anymore.

Comment: still not work  image source error

Comment: Could you share the error after pub cache clean?

Comment: [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:image_cropper_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_image_cropper.dart': Failed assertion: line 72 pos 12: 'await File(sourcePath).exists()': is not true.
E/flutter (16075): #0 _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:51:61)
E/flutter (16075): #1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:40:5)
E/flutter (16075): #2  MethodChannelImageCropper.cropImage (package:image_cropper_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_image_cropper.dart:72:12)

Comment: E/flutter (16075): #3      _MovableImageBoxState._cropImage (package:invitation_card_app/widgets/MovableImageBox.dart:432:26)
E/flutter (16075): <asynchronous suspension>
Error come from this line
    final croppedImage = await ImageCropper().cropImage
when the await call the app is crash